# Finding a beta of a regression from two regressions on distinct samples

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a lot off observations for 10 years for the same variables but the computer can not run a regression with all observations appended. Is there a way to find the final beta using each beta calculated in each regression by year?

in short, I would like to obtain lm_tot result using lm_1 and lm_2. Is it possible?

```
#### ---------- Example using R

  DT_1   <- data.frame(female=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0), salary=c(800,390,480,780,801,120,500), kids=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0))
  DT_2   <- data.frame(female=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0), salary=c(378,690,480,780,753,251,584), kids=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1))
  DT_tot <- rbind(DT_1,DT_2) 
# regression by sex
  lm_1 <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_1)
  lm_2 <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_2)
  lm_tot <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_tot)

# results 
 # lm_1
  Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       female         kids  
        650.0       -332.2        130.0  

 # lm_2
  Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       female         kids  
        692.1       -153.3       -117.2  

 # lm_total
  Coefficients:
  (Intercept)       female         kids  
       681.33      -183.67       -51.78
```